# Divide Swift String into groups of 3 symbols

Tags: string, swift, divide

I'm making a formatter for currency string, for example I have `Int`:

```
let a: Int = 10
let b: Int = 10000
let c: Int = 10000000
```

I want them to be formatted like:

```
let a1:String = "10"
let b1:String = "10 000"
let c1:String = "10 000 000"
```

So I need funtion (or extension) in `Swift` as elegant, as you can suggest =) You have a `Int` as input parameter and you should output it as a `String` with " "(space symbol) every 3 symbols from right to left.

Comment: This needs to be expanded to include more context. Are the three examples given the only format you would expect? Will it always be "M"? Would "1000 M" be "1 000 M"?

Comment: Have a look at NSNumberFormatter ...

Comment: @SteveWilford edited

Answer (score 0):

this may help you :

```
func formatNumberString(number : String?) -> String?
    {
        //"10 000 000 M"
        // 01234567890123   -> 2,6,10

        if (number?.isEmpty == true || number?.length <= 2) {
            return number
        }

        var i : Int = 0
        var newNumber : String = ""
        for character in (number?.characters)! {
            if ((i == 2 || i == 6 || i == 10) && character != " ")
            {
                newNumber = newNumber + " "
            }
            i++
        }

        return newNumber
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should user `NSNumberFormatter` to format your number:

```
    func numberToCurrency(number: Int) -> String {
        let formatter: NSNumberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()

        formatter.numberStyle = .CurrencyStyle

        formatter.positiveSuffix = " M"
        formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
        formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator = " "
        formatter.usesGroupingSeparator = true
        return formatter.stringFromNumber(number)!
    }
```

`print(numberToCurrency(1000))` will print `1 000 M`. If you don't want to show `M` character, just set `formatter.positiveSuffix = ""`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as extension and just call if input is string

```
let requiredN =  "10000000".convertToFormat()
```

this is the extension for string

```
extension String

{
    func convertToFormat() -> String
    {
        return (NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(Int(self)!, numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle) as String).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: " ")

    }
}
```

If input value is Int call

```
let requiredN =  10000000.convertToFormat()
```

and extension for Int

```
extension Int

{
    func convertToFormat() -> String
    {
        return (NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(self, numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle) as String).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: " ")

    }
}
```

Comment: @katleta3000 Did you try using it?